# Looking for a great Ajax enabled datagrid that will work with .net MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am researching writing a website in Asp.Net MVC 2, it will rely heavily on a datagrid control for showing data and editing data. Ideally it would support AJAX so the page doesn't have to reload with every update.

Rather than writing this from scratch, does anybody know of a really great, well supported 3rd party control for doing this?

I am just starting to learn about Asp.Net MVC, thanks for you're help

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the great responses, really helpful, has any body tried both of the suggestions below, does anybody have any information on the pros and cons of both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try 
Telerik MVC grid

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx

MVContrib grid

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&ProjectName=mvccontrib

Answer (score 5):

jQGrid.

http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Instructions on use with asp.net mvc (may be a bit outdated):

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you look for a CRUD datagrid for asp.net MVC there is one in my [MVC Controls Toolkit](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/).It allows Editing in place, deletion insertion, sorting, undo of all changes not yet committed,  **and can be sychronized with a companion Ajax enabled detail View helper**.It doesn't require any call to Json action method or web service but updates directly a collection that is passed to the controller. Sorting is returned as a list of lambda expression that can be immediately used into a Linq query. [Here](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/releases) you can download a complete example that includes also a database. While [here](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid%20and%20Pager%20Complete%20Example) you can see a picture of the grid working.
while [here](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2010/11/15/Defining-MVC-Controls-3-Datagrid-Sorting-and-Master-Detail-Views.aspx) and [here](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2010/10/30/Defining-MVC-Controls-2-Using-the-DataGrid.aspx) you can read tutorials